# Just moved to Netherlands for a couple of years, but I am on US payroll. Do I need to pay dutch tax?

Tags: usa, taxes, netherlands

I moved to Netherlands with my family about a month ago. I am on the US payroll and receive bi-weekly pay checks in the US. Do I need to pay income tax in Netherlands? In order for me to get housing, I had to apply for the resident number(BSN), so I suppose I am considered a resident here. Also, if I do have to pay tax, then how do I file for the 30% ruling? My company is headquartered in USA, with a small regional office in the Netherlands. However, I am still under the USA contract. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a work permit?

Comment: There are all sorts of international and bilateral tax / national social insurance treaties/agreements  which govern these things. The rule of thumb is (supposed to be) that you don't pay taxes twice on the same income nor evade paying taxes completely, but that's not a specific answer to your question. Perhaps you should start by reading the WikiPedia [article on tax residence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_residence).

Comment: I'm in the same situation, except with Japan and Germany. You're usually paying taxes in your primary place of residence, which is typically defined as the place where you spend >50% of the year.

Comment: @deceze usually, yes. But the US taxes its citizens' worldwide income regardless of their place of residence.

Comment: @phoog - yes I have a work permit. I was told that without a work permit, I can work in Netherlands only for 6 months.

Comment: @deceze I guess I'll be spending more than 50% of my time in Netherlands . However, I am already being taxed (Federal + State + Social) on my salary in US.

Comment: @einplklum Thanks for the link. As phoog pointed out, I'll get taxed in US regardless of my place of residence.

Comment: @AVP I'll admit to being ignorant of the US tax law. I'd pay a tax consultant for advice and/or to handle your taxes, if I were you… Not least because filling in Dutch tax forms might be a challenge. :)

Comment: Thanks, and I agree. Just wanted to check if there is anyone else in a similar boat. One dilemma I have is whether I should file (or if I am eligible) for the 30% rule, it would suck to find out at the time of filing taxes that I was eligible.

Comment: For the IRS you may qualify for the foreign earned income exclusion. You will also get a credit for tax paid to the Netherlands. If you pay any tax to the IRS at all, it will almost certainly be far less than the tax paid to the Netherlands.

Comment: Thanks Phoog, would you know if would be eligible for the 30% ruling?